# I'm trying to use a code to display score in the UI text but it didn't show up/change the text object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    
    public class wastafel : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Text ctText;
        public static int iscucitangan;//scoring
        public int handwash;
    
        void update()
        {
            handwash = iscucitangan;
            ctText.text = "Sudah cuci tangan :" + handwash;
        }

 }
```

I tried this script to display a scoring system I made in unity (I use this video as reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKeXyaB41EA). I applied this code to a text UI object in my program [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdhGU.png). [This is the CT text object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I5FM.png). But when I press play, it came up [like this, no change at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoERt.png).
[This is my text setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G3t3.png). Is there something that I miss?

Answer (score 0):

It is caused because of the typo, it should be `Update()` with a capital `U` and not `update()`.